# Android: file permissions on external storage folder

Tags: android, file-permissions, malware, android-external-storage

I would like to know if it is possible to set the permissions of the files that my Android app writes on behalf of the user in the external storage folder (that is the common user folders that are accessible to my app like "Documents") so that those files are not writable by other applications that know where they are or explore the external storage folders to find them.

I mean, if my application has many installations and it becomes the target of malware apps, and it has a known user files folder, the malware could change or delete those files (json and other types like txt, doc). I would like that it is not possible by means of file permissions setting.

But note that the user has to be able to manage those files and also edit them.

Even my app sends intents so other apps edit them.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. If you do not want other apps to have access to the files, put them on internal storage, not external storage.

Comment: Is it possible to at least set some "read only" attribute on an external storage file, to protect the user from accidentally deleting something?
Of course the user could change that attribute...

Comment: @SirKnigget: No, sorry, Android does not have an option for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create encrypted storage with consistency checking instead of using permissions, what is not possible.